# Multi level SQL join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 different tables names as state, config, and user

```
state: columns
--------------
taskid
class
state
queue time
running time

config: columns
---------------
class
confname

user: columns
-------------
username
userid
```

I can join the `state` and `config` tables using **class** column, but in my result set, I want to add the username as well, but there is not matching columns to join. But I can do this via inclusing one more table `tasks`  that has a relationship with the `state` table.

```
tasks: columns
--------------
taskid,
userid,
taskname
```

Using this table, I want to generate the output columns like below.

```
username - from users table
confname - from config table
state, queue time, running time - from the state table
```

I tried the following query, but its giving zero results. Can someone help me with the better logic?

```sql
select
p.username,
c.confname,
s.state,
s.queue_time/1000000 ||' sec' as queue_time,
s.exec_time/1000000 ||' sec' as execution_time
from
    state as s join
    config c on s.class=c.class
     join ((select distinct(userid)as user from taks q join  state s on q.taskid=s.taskid) j
      join 
     user p on j.user=p.username)
```

Comment: Creating [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) will encourage everyone to answers. This will help trying the SQLs.

Comment: If you create the many-to-many table after loading your data... there is no way to populate it using a query (or query it)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a syntax error.  There are more `join`s than `on`s.

You are describing something like this:

```
from state s join
     config c
     on s.class = c.class left join
     task t
     on j.taskid = s.taskid left join 
     user u
     on t.user = u.username
```

Of course, if there are no matching tasks or users, then those columns will be empty.